# Manage add-ins ribbon in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm doing a project and it's based on a previous Access project.

The DB I need to use is only accessed via the "Add-ins" tab, where I can find different buttons and tools to access the database.
For some reason I can't copy/paste or export the table to txt or excel spreadsheet, so I'm trying to find a way to manage the add-ins and access the table directly.

I can't find that table in the navigation bar (All Access Objects), so I guess this is the only way for me to find said table.
How do I reach the tables or queries defined in the add-ins tab?

Going to file->options->add-ins shows me that there are no add-ins installed

Comment: You haven't provided any code for analysis. Question is not really suited to SO. Is the db a split design? Is the frontend an accdb file? Do you know where the other file is located? If so, set a link to that other db table and do what  you want with it. Your 'add-ins' might just be a customized ribbon with buttons that execute plain old VBA code behind the db.

Comment: This is not really "too broad". If you have never seen how old custom menu bars migrated into the new ribbon world, this is exactly the question you have - *where are those menus stored, and what do they do??*

Comment: @Andre I tend to sort-of agree, but the question is one long block of unorganized text, and I'm having trouble following it. If you can edit it into shape a bit, I'll certainly cast a reopen vote

Comment: @ErikA: yeah, I know. Problem is, the question is based on the assumption that the menu is stored in a table, and I don't want to completely rewrite it. So only cosmetic changes done.

Comment: @Andre That already helps a lot for readability imo, cosmetic changes can help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Add-Ins" tab you see old custom menus, which are [`CommandBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/library-reference/commandbar-members-office) objects.

There is no table for them, the following function lists all custom menus and should get you started.
Output is in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).

```vb
Public Function ListCustomCommandBars()

    Dim cbarMenu As CommandBar
    Dim Oberpunkt As CommandBarControl
    Dim Unterpunkt As CommandBarControl

    ' ignore errors, e.g. menu items having no .OnAction property
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cbarMenu In CommandBars
        If Not cbarMenu.BuiltIn Then
            Debug.Print vbCrLf & "=== " & cbarMenu.Name & " ===" & vbCrLf
            For Each Oberpunkt In cbarMenu.Controls
                Debug.Print Oberpunkt.Index & " " & IIf(Not Oberpunkt.Visible, "(--) ", "") & Oberpunkt.Caption
                For Each Unterpunkt In Oberpunkt.Controls
                    Debug.Print , Unterpunkt.Index & " " & IIf(Not Unterpunkt.Visible, "(--) ", "") & Unterpunkt.OnAction, Unterpunkt.Caption
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

The most interesting part is `.OnAction` - it shows what a menu item does.