# Where is the "Add-Ins" custom menu stored in an office VBA application?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, toolbar, office-addins

I am working on a legacy MS Access 2010 database project, and I cannot find where I can review and edit the custom "Add-Ins" toolbar. This is the custom toolbar:

[Add-Ins tool bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97IMU.png)

This project was previously migrated from a version prior to the ribbon world, hence I am not able to find any table or xml file with the custom toolbar menu. I can only show and hide the Add-Ins toolbar here:

[Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuVuy.png)

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118155/4042343) that the custom toolbar is contained in some CommandBar object, but I still cannot find where it is defined and how to modify the toolbar and the actions on button clicks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a function inside a module which is creating the menus. It seems that in this case, the menus are manually created/updated running that function manually, so I had to go to view code (Alt+F11), place the cursor inside the function and hit F5 to execute.

One sample of code how to create/edit custom menus with this technique can be found [here](https://quadexcel.com/wp/how-to-create-a-menu-with-vba/), but in the new versions of office VBA can be done like [this](https://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Access_-_Ribbons).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @intotecho, thanks for your suggestion. I added more detailed info.

Answer (score 2):

Check under access options, current database ..............
It is likely it was created using macros, so you need to find the name of the macro, then edit the macro if need be.

i have attached two images.

1. Shows the name of the macro under access options
2. Shows the location of the macro under macro sections in navigation

[image: Access options]

[image: Navigation Pane]

Comment: This was indeed very close, but this project does not have macros. The menus are built from the code as you mention. I finally found the function which created them inside one of the hundreds of modules of the project. Thanks!